# bcrypt.compare() return false in postman

Tags: node.js, express

This `validPassword` gives Wrong Password in Postman, or it gives status code **400**, but I want to return user and status code **200**.

```js
//login
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
  !user && res.status(404).json('user not found')
  //req.body.password user.password
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
  !validPassword && res.status(400).json('Wrong Password')

  res.status(200).json(user)
 } catch (err) {
  res.status(500).json(err)
 }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: IMO, `!user && res.status(404).json("user not found")` is not good practice and also does not stop the function from executing. Change it to `if (!user) return res.status(404).json("user not found")`. Same for the other check.